# The _redirect() function in zend framework

Tags: function, class, zend-framework, redirect, layout

I made a file in library/My/Utils/Utils.php. The content of the file is :

```
class My_Utils_Utils{
    public function test(){
        $this->_redirect('login');   
    }
}
```

This class is called from a layout; the problem is with the `_redirect();`  I get this error : The page isn't redirecting properly. My question is how call the `_redirect()` function from a class made by you in ZEND framework 1 .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: A very simlar question here, maybe it's usefult for your need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913509/zend-redirect-to-action-with-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Use `redirect()` instead of `_redirect()`. Usage is:

```
$this->redirect(<action>, <controller>, <module>, <param>);
```

In your case `$this->redirect('login');` should do the trick.

Comment: it doesn't :( . Actually the redirect('') function it doesnt exits in zend, maybe at codeigniter. In zend is _rediect('') with underscore.

Comment: @Naghi
_redirect() method is deprecated as of Zend Framework 1.7. Use redirect() instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [redirector action-helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html), which you can get statically from the `HelperBroker` using:

```
// get the helper
$redirectHelper = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('redirector');

// call methods on the helper
$redirect->gotoUrl('/some/url');
```

It should be noted, however, that the layout is considered part of the view layer. Typically, any checks that result in a redirect should probably take place earlier in the request dispatch-cycle, typically in a controller or in a [front-controller plugin](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.plugins.html).

Comment: believe I already tried it. The fact is if I call the class and the function from a controller , it works, but if i call it from a layout it doesnt. any ideas why ?

Comment: please dont send me the documentation from zend. Im a newbie I want proper examples, not teory. thx for understanding me

Comment: Aah, probably need to use `gotoUrlAndExit()`, instead. That will actually trigger the redirect, not just set the headers in the response object.

Answer (score 0):

The _redirect function is provided by the class Zend_Controller_Action. You can fix this in two ways :

1. Extend Zend_Controller_Action and use _redirect

   ```
   class My_Utils_Utils extends Zend_Controller_Action {
      public function test(){
       $this->_redirect('login');   
      }
   ```

   }

**in layout:**

```
     $request = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest();
     $response = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getResponse()
     $util = new My_Utils_Utils($request, $response); // The constructor for Zend_Controller_Action required request and response params.
    $util->test();
```

1. Use gotoUrl() function Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Redirector::gotoUrl()

   ```
    $redirector = new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Redirector();
    $redirector->gotoUrl('login');

    //in layout : 
    $util = new My_Utils_Utils();
    $util->test();
   ```

Comment: believe I already tried it. The fact is if I call the class and the function from a controller , it works, but if i call it from a layout it doesnt.